# Shell glob expansion after loop variable substitution

Tags: bash, wildcards

How can the following be changed example so that it does glob expansion after loop variable substitution?

```
for i in a b c
    do echo $i/*.txt
done
```

UPDATE: This normally does work, however `set -f` had been done earlier in the script I'm looking at.

Comment: How does it "not work" at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing `bash` code, judicious use of "set -f" to turn off globbing, and "set +f" to turn globbing on might do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in a b c
do
    set -f
    Z=$i/*.txt
    echo $Z
    set +f
    echo
    echo "Does it expand?"
    echo $Z
done
```